# nav drawer fragment item fill parent

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to get the fragments within the nav drawer to fill the screen (match_parent) i.e. user selects settings inside drawer, settings frag opens filling the screen. However with my current layout the parent (main) activity with test button remains on screen i.e. the fragment is not filling the screen only a portion. I'm pretty new to working with frags and nag drawer, i'm sure its simple, any help appreciated.

My activity layout xml with fragment container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_category"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Movies"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.app.fragments.MainDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_main_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve this one with a better understanding of nav drawer.

I have removed the button from DrawerLayout above and instead created a "home" fragment which is element 0 in drawer ArrayList (and added button here), I have set main activity to call displayView() on fragment at element 0 (with the button from above), now settings is e.g in element 1 in ArrayList and simply when selected overlays element 0 (home).

Not sure if its the correct fix but works fine now.